# Is there anyway to increase the bass in Jelly Bean?

Tags: audio, samsung-galaxy-s-4

I know the iphone had a similar feature built in. I'm using a Samsung Galaxy S4 with Android version 4.2.2

Comment: Have you tried to use one of the [many equalizer apps at Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=equalizer&c=apps)?

Comment: @Izzy Ah, perfect!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the built-in graphic equalizer by going to **Settings**, then **Sound**, then **Audio effects**.